# giraph fails only on large graphs after warn "likely client has closed socket"

Tags: apache-zookeeper, giraph

I'm using giraph-1.3.0.-SNAPSHOT and hadoop-2.8.4 in a EC2 cluster composed of 5 nodes (everyone has 32 cpus and 60 GBs ram).

If I give small input to my algorithm implemented in giraph, It properly works. When I give a large input (like https://snap.stanford.edu/data/web-NotreDame.html) I obtains this warn and after a while my giraph run fails.

```
WARN server.NIOServerCnxn: caught end of stream exception EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid  likely client has closed socket
```

I think it is related to zookeeper but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

How much memory did you allocate for the JVM where Giraph runs?
It looks like a typical out of memory error